# is there a way to only get one of the duplicates in a queryste? django

Tags: python, django, duplicates, django-queryset

I am not trying to get all duplicate `querysets` and I am not trying to compare two `queryset` results and see of the two comparison are the same.

Somehow, I have no idea how this happened yet but sometimes there are records being saved twice and some not.  So when I do `querying` my result would sometimes have duplicates.

For example, I am just doing `Model.objects.filter(user='myname')`

I would get maybe 50 `instances` back, all of them should be different.  But somehow maybe id `11` and `12` have the exact same values then `23` and `24` has the same values and the others are totally fine.

So actually within those 50 `instances`, there are 2 `duplicates` which means I should only have 48 `instances` instead of 50 to be accurrate.

Is there a way to check the queryset and return only one of the duplicates with other querysets if the values are totally the same?

Comment: Why don't you set `unique=True` in models?

Comment: You're misusing the name "queryset" here. A queryset is a *set* of things, that represents a query. The individual things are model instances. You have one queryset containing 50 instances.

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge it's not just one field

Answer (score 0):

you can do that using distinct in your orm query eg.`Model.objects.filter(user='myname').distinct('field_name')`
this will give you only distinct values based on the field that you provide.

Answer (score 0):

Above **.distinct('field_name')** is one solution. But this only works with POSTGRE SQL. But doesn't work with MySQL.

For **POSTGRESQL** Simply after your queryset add below statement:

```
queryset = queryset.distinct('field_name')
```

For **MySQL**. Simply after your queryset add below statement:

```
queryset = queryset.distinct()
```